# プロキシ環境下でnginxのリバースプロキシを使うには

Tags: nginx

会社のネットワークが認証付きプロキシなのですが
この環境下でnginxのリバースプロキシを動作させたいです。

単純にproxy_passを設定するだけでは、認証付きプロキシを突破できないので
nginx側に認証付きプロキシの設定を行いたいのですが可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

リバースプロキシー先のWebサーバーを、フォワードプロキシ経由で参照したいということでしょうか？
多分、認証なしだとしても、フォワードプロキシ経由でWebサーバーを参照することはできないと思います。
URI の解析で、http[s]://host:port/uri?args の「/uri」箇所が「/」から始まっていないとシンタックスエラーとなり、フォワードプロキシーに「http://」などで始まる URI を渡すことができません。